# Burning [books]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[books](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/books) is a very ambiguous tag. It's use is varied, although generally it is used by questions looking for book recommendations. It heralds from the era of ['09](https://superuser.com/questions/64124/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-scanned-book)

A [lot](https://superuser.com/questions/67062/excel-for-programmers) of the [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/76027/best-tool-for-writing-a-programming-book) [are](https://superuser.com/questions/156270/books-for-understanding-how-computers-work) [closed](https://superuser.com/questions/160455/good-books-for-learning-excel-vba) and have been for years, and could probably be deleted along with this tag cleanup.